# Solve using Bayes?

Tags: probability

I'm trying to become more comfortable using Bayes or Conditional probability. I have the answer to this problem, but I'm wondering how to go about it in a more formal way. Care to help??

> Do like you did before by considering both scenarios. One scenario is that you drew the biased coin and it came up heads $5$ times. That has probability $\frac15\cdot 1 = \frac15$. The other scenario is that you drew a fair coin, and it came up heads $5$ times. That has probability $\frac45\cdot\frac1{32} = \frac1{40}$. So biased is a $\frac15 : \frac1{40}$ or $8:1$ favorite over fair, so the probability that it is biased is $\frac89$, and the probability that it is fair is $\frac19$. The probability that it comes up heads on the next flip is

$$\frac89\cdot 1 +\frac19\cdot 0.5 = \frac{17}{18}\;.$$

Bayes theory is this right?

$$\Bbb P(A\mid B)=\frac{\Bbb P(B\mid A)\cdot\Bbb P(A)}{\Bbb P(B)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the probability that the coin drawn is biassed can indeed be done with Bayes’ theorem. Let $A$ be the event that you drew the biassed coin, and let $B$ be the event that the coin came up heads $5$ times; then you want $\Bbb P(A\mid B)$, the probability that it’s biassed given that it came up heads all $5$ times. Bayes’ theorem says that this is

$$\frac{\Bbb P(B\mid A)\cdot\Bbb P(A)}{\Bbb P(B)}\;.$$

It’s easy to compute $\Bbb P(B\mid A)$: if you drew the biassed coin, the probability of getting $5$ heads in $5$ tosses is $1$. You also know that $\Bbb P(A)=\frac15$. Calculating $\Bbb P(B)$ is a bit more work: it’s given by

$$\Bbb P(B)=\Bbb P(B\mid A)\cdot\Bbb P(A)+\Bbb P(B\mid\neg A)\cdot\Bbb P(\neg A)\;,$$

where $\neg A$ is not-$A$, the event that you drew the fair coin. This is

$$\Bbb P(B)=1\cdot\frac15+\left(\frac12\right)^5\cdot\frac45=\frac15+\frac1{40}=\frac9{40}\;,$$

so

$$\Bbb P(A\mid B)=\frac{1\cdot\frac15}{\frac9{40}}=\frac15\cdot\frac{40}9=\frac89\;.$$

As you can see, it’s pretty much what was done in the statement of the problem; I’ve just identified each piece with the appropriate element of Bayes’ theorem.